# How to power a voltage divider with 2.1V

Tags: power-supply, adc, voltage-divider

I have a 3.3V circuit with an ADC chip that reads values between 0V and 2.1V, that means anything above 2.1V will return 2047. If I use a voltage divider with the Vcc power supply, I would lose a lot of range. What is the best solution to measure all values? Do I have to buy a 2.1V regulator? Or can I supply 2.1V with another voltage divider?

The variable resistor in that provides the voltage to measure would be a potentiometer or a light sensor (photoresistor).

Comment: The normal setup for a photoresistor/potentiometer setup _is_ a potential divider, so I'm confused by "would lose a lot of range". You can place a resistor of suitable size towards the positive side of the supply, which is going to constrain the maximum voltage output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a photoresistor that varies (for example) from 10 MOhms with no light, to 100 Ohms with bright light, the following voltage divider arrangement would provide a 0-2.1 Volt range as desired, with a 3.3 Volt supply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZiBxE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At pitch dark, this would yield 2.1 Volts, while at maximum light, it would be approximately 0 Volts.

In order to take better advantage of say the 100 Ohm to 1 MOhm range of the photoresistor and consider anything above 1 MOhm as "too dark", R1+R2 can be chosen to total 570 kOhms, instead of the 5.7 MOhms shown.